# Uninstalling old Mac OS apps in my Macbook Air

Tags: macos, mac

I have these 2 applications sitting in my Macbook Air Applications folder. I am currently running High Sierra and not planning to upgrade to either of these 2 versions. Is it OK to uninstall them or will their removal cause issues? Its currently taking up 11 GB and I want to free up some space.

[image: The screenshot from my Macbook]

Comment: Notice that the Sierra icon has a "no entry" sign, because Sierra is older than your current OS. So technically, that would be a 'downgrade', and is more complicated than just launching the installer app.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't notice that. Thank you. I will remove it then. Is Mojave higher to High Sierra and that's why it doesn't have the "no entry" sign?

Comment: Yes, Sierra is macOS 10.12, High Sierra 10.13 & Mojave 10.14 [After that comes Catalina, 10.15 & Big Sur, which I think is going to be macOS 11]

Answer (score 8):

It is perfectly safe to delete unwanted macOS Installers - simply drag them to the trash [& empty it to recover the disk space], nothing further required.

You can always get them again if you need them.
Ordinarily, after a successful upgrade, the system would delete them itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is totally ok to delete them if you have already upgraded.

Comment: Someone downvoted me. If you downvoted me, can you at least tell me why? Just wondering since I can always edit...